# Tkinter event binding of entry widget for password verification

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use a entry widget for password input, a handler function for password verification and a label widget for displaying the result of the verification. The code is as following so far,

```
class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        #Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        super(LoginFrame, self).__init__()

        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    # initialize the login screen UI  
    def initUI(self):
        # Set up login frame properties 
        self.parent.title("Login Screen")

        # creating instruction label
        inst_lbl = self.make_label(self.parent, "Please login to continue")

        # creating labels and entries for user name and password
        user_name = self.make_entry(self.parent, caption="User Name:")
        pwd = self.make_entry(self.parent, caption="User Password:", show="*")

        # create a login button
        login_btn = self.make_button(self.parent, self.verify_user, "Login")        


    # create a button 
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def make_button(self, parent, command, caption=NONE, side=TOP, width=0, **options):
    """make a button"""
        btn = Button(parent, text=caption, command=command)

        if side is not TOP:
           btn.pack(side=side)
        else:
           btn.pack()    

        return btn


   def make_label(self, parent, caption=NONE, side=TOP, **options):
       label = Label(parent, text=caption, **options)

       if side is not TOP:
           label.pack(side=side)
       else:
           label.pack()

       return label


   def make_entry(self, parent, caption=NONE, side=TOP, width=0, **options):
       #Label(parent, text=caption).pack(side=LEFT)
       self.make_label(self.parent, caption, side)
       entry = Entry(parent, **options)
       if width:
          entry.config(width=width)
       if side is not TOP:
          entry.pack(side=side)
       else:
          entry.pack()

       return entry        


   # verify user name and password
   #----------------------------------------------------------------------
   def verify_user(event):
       """verify users"""
       if user_name.get() == "admin" and pwd.get() == "123":
           #inst_lbl.configure(text="User verified")
           event.widget.config(text="User verified")
       else:
           #inst_lbl.configure(text="Access denied. Invalid username or password")
           event.widget.config(text="Access denied. Invalid username or password")


def main():
    top = Tk()    
    app = LoginFrame(top)
    top.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

now, I need `user_name` and `pwd` to be verified by the method `verify_user`, the result is shown in `inst_lbl` whenever the button `login_btn` is clicked (to trigger the verification). So how to bind `inst_lbl` to `verify_user`, in response to the `login_btn` click event? and how to get the contents of `user_name` and `pwd` to get verified in `verify_user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them class variable by adding `self.` prefixes. This way you can access them outside of the method they are created.

```
self.inst_lbl = self.make_label(...)
self.user_name = self.make_entry(...)
self.pwd = self.make_entry(...)
```

When trying to call them, you also will need `self.` prefixes.

```
self.inst_lbl.configure(...)
```

Other than that, you'll be needing `self` parameter in `verify_user` method since it's a member of a class.

Also, for Python-2.x, you'll get `TypeError: must be type, not classobj` on your `super(LoginFrame, self).__init__()`. The line you commented out is the right one to use.

```
Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

If you want to use `super()`, you should add `object` as parameter to your class definiton because of old style classes etc.

```
class LoginFrame(Frame, object):
```

Comment: since class `LoginFrame` inherits `Frame`, how to use `super()` properly in `__init__()` for this case?

Comment: I run the code with `super()`, but there wasn't any error generated.

Comment: Yeah, that error occured because of python 2. Sorry, I should mention it. For python 2, you need to add object to parameters of LoginFrame like this. `class LoginFrame(Frame, object)`. For python 3, it should work fine.